# Targetting div by ID with chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use chrome.tabs.executeScript to target a specific div on my page.

```
function click(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"document.body.div#wrap.style.color='" + e.target.id + "'"});
  window.close();
}
```

Consule is telling me: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

---

Is this a syntax problem, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) instead of the syntactically invalid `div#wrap`:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: "document.querySelector('div#wrap').style.color='" + e.target.id + "';"
});
```